# JasperReports accessing method on bean datasource?

Tags: java, jasper-reports, javabeans

I'm using *JasperReports* and I'm using the provided `JRBeanCollectionDataSource` class to wrap a `List` of beans. Everything works fine in my reports when I'm accessing a simple property of the bean, but what I really need to do is access a few methods on the class. For example I would like to access the method:

```
public List<Date> getCertifications(Date postedBy);
```

How would I go about accessing this in the *JRXML* (or *iReport*)? If I define a field such as

```
<field name="certifications" class="java.util.List"/>
```

then I get an error that the property is unknown.

Thanks for the help!

> JasperReports: version 3.7.3

Answer (score 0):

What date will you pass? I think, with JRXML you can only define bean properties - i.e. the ones that have a standard setter and getter. Everything else you can invoke from expressions.

Comment: The date is a parameter to the report. That part I have figured out. How would I use an expression to access the current object that the report is using? i.e. how would I call getCertifications( new java.util.Date() ) from a textFieldExpression if getCertifications( Date ) is a method on a PersonBean and the report's datasource is a Collection of PersonBeans? Thanks.

Comment: @Josh I know this is old but check out the answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6638569/jasper-report-how-to-call-a-java-bean-method-in-report-template for getting the `PersonBean`.