# JasperReports: How to call a java bean method in report template?

Tags: java, jasper-reports, javabeans

I am passing a java bean collection into a jasper report. I have several fields for this java bean defined an they are display just fine in my report.

Im wondering if there is a way to call a method of a java bean that is being passed into this report???

E.g. an expression for a text field, something like....

```
{current java bean}.methodToCall()
```

Answer (score 21):

Using the keyword `_THIS` in a field name or description will make it map to the bean class itself. Using the fieldDescription tag is better as it allows you to do this with multiple beans.

For example:

```
<field name="customBean" class="com.example.customBean">
    <fieldDescription>_THIS</fieldDescription>
</field>
```

Then you can call methods in an expression like this:

```
<textFieldExpression>$F{customBean}.someMethod()</textFieldExpression>
```

Comment: Is possible to do that without using `<textField/>` ? I need to call some method, but with no output on report. Now i return "" in that method, but it is not elegant.

Comment: @marioosh You should be able to call it in any expression, so if you have no content you might try creating a dummy variable in the report and use the `initialValueExpression` to make the call.

Comment: @GenericJon "com.example.customBean" where is this class defined in jasper report. I am trying this but my class is not found by template. Do we need to import this class somewhere? and How? I am using jasper 6.13 version

Comment: @Bugs-notabug That's an example. Replace it with the bean that you want to reference.