# How to call entity method in jasper report?

Tags: java, spring

I can't call spring mvc entity method into jasper report. Here is the method which I want to call in jasper report.

```
public BigDecimal getOutstanding(){
        BigDecimal currentBalance = this.getCurrentBalance() != null ? this.getCurrentBalance() : new BigDecimal(0);
        BigDecimal payableAmount = this.getPayableAmount() != null ? this.getPayableAmount() : new BigDecimal(0);
        return payableAmount.subtract(currentBalance);
    }
```

I have tried the following way:

```
 <field name="customer" class="com.rightbrainsolution.titas.domesticbilling.entities.Customer"/>

<textField>
                <reportElement x="810" y="-15" width="210" height="14" uuid="91aaf617-bd64-4406-a74e-9c9eee52db56"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{customer}.getOutstanding()]]></textFieldExpression>
</textField>
```

But not working  says :

[ERROR] Could not compile outstanding.jrxml
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JRValidationException: Report design not valid : 
     1. java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.rightbrainsolution.titas.domesticbilling.entities.Customer

Comment: As the error tells you: Your `Customer` class is not on jasper's classpath when you try to generate the report. It's not a problem with calling the property accessor (you don't get that far).

Comment: Add Customer to your jasper report's classpath

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't call a `method` of custom class. you can call a method of class if you have a compiled version of a class imported and then you can follow [the post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6648501/1289495).

As I can see, you have a getter method `getOutstanding` you can simply use the `outstanding` as a field(Though the `outstanding` is not a real field) like

```
<textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{outstanding}]]></textFieldExpression>
```